# Unable to get Post Category Name and URL

Tags: php, posts, categories

I am very new to wordpress development, please help me out in getting post's category name and its url.

I have tried get_the_category() function but it didn't helped me. Following it the code snippet:

```
     <div class="post-meta-categories"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php get_the_category(); >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why `get_the_category();` didn't work we have to take a closer look at the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#return) page for that function. More specifically, what that function returns.

> (array) Array of WP_Term objects, one for each category assigned to the post.

You tried to print an Array to HTML, which is why it didn't work.

Instead, take a look at the `get_the_category_list()` function as seen on the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/), which says:

> Retrieve category list in either HTML list or custom format.

You also forgot to end your php snippet with a `?>`. So to wrap it all up...

```
<div class="post-meta-categories"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php echo get_the_category_list(','); ?></div>
```

Which returns a list of comma separated post categories with clickable links.